# Where is my standard "Edit" button

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to make a custom object available in lightning.

I need to have all standard buttons on this record page.

But I cannot find the "Edit" standard button for "Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions".

As you can see in the image - there is no edit button to select from:

[image]

I have full access to the object, and in classic salesforce all is ok.

What can be my problem?

Comment: Did you overwrite your Edit button by any chance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you have overwrite your standard Edit button with a Visualforce Page and page is not available for Salesforce1. To make your visualforce page available for Salesforce1 and Lightning go to

Setup - > Develop -> Visualforce Pages -> Your visualforce page -> Click Edit -> Check Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages checkbox -> Save

After this you can see your button appear on Salesforce1 action on the layout.